# Eclipse : Java : OpenCV : "The import org cannot be resolved."

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, opencv, compilation

I compiled OpenCV on Linux (Mint 19 Tara), I used this tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

Then I tried to use the library like that: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d0a/tutorial_java_eclipse.html

But in the imports I get an error: "The import org cannot be resolved."

What can I do wrong? Here is the code I used:

```
package com.thegergo02.facedetection;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
public class Hello
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
      Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
      System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
   }
}
```

[Package Explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXfQB.png)

The compile was successful, no errors, i had Java, Ant, everything.

Java version: jdk-11.0.1
Ant version: 1.10.3

Comment: As the error itself say the package library org cannot be resolved means it is not installed properly. try using `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`

Comment: But I did everything the tutorial(s) said. What can I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Where did I have to put that line? Because it's in the main function already.

Comment: Did you run 'make install' to get a kind of SDK in the <build>/install
folder?
Did you tried 'Fix project properties' for the OpenCV library project?

Comment: Where do I find the 'Fix project properties'? I try recompiling it with that command.

Comment: Recompiling doesn't worked, I still can't find that button. (The recompiling was really fast this time, is this a problem?)

Comment: Can you please check in your Project->Build path->your library if open cv is present there if not then add external jars and selct open cv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the default package, **delete the file `module-info.java`**.

The tutorial is based on Java 6 without the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) in mind which can (but does not have to) be used since Java 9.

If using JPMS, the dependency to the OpenCV module must be explicitly defined in the `module-info.java` file to make it accessible.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you, I can't believe this is the solution to a problem I could not fix in 1 day.